# Performing reverse UK postcode lookup on Bing maps

Tags: bing-maps

we need to get the complete postcode of a UK address but we are getting only the short part of it using Bing Maps API (or the tool). If we search for "LA7 7NH" in the tool it shows us the location on the map but if we add a marker there we get only "LA77".

What do we need to do to get the full postcode? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I got a confirmation email from Microsoft indicating that this is the expected behavior.

So ... its a feature, not a bug.